# HttpHandler not working in IIS 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7, httphandler

I have an HttpHandler configured in my web.config file like so:

```
<add verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
     path="TinyMCE.ashx"
     type="Moxiecode.TinyMCE.Web.HttpHandler,Moxiecode.TinyMCE" />
```

When I deploy to IIS 7 the handler stops working (404).

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Registration of HttpHandlers is different for IIS7 than for previous versions of IIS. Specifically, you register the handlers in the web.config section named `<system.webServer><handlers>` not in `<httpHandlers>`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272971/custom-http-handlers-iis7-and-asp-net/1273021#1273021) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

We have a legacy application where changing the webconfig to user system.webServer -> handlers was not an option. We solved this 404 issue by setting the application pool's "Managed Pipeline Mode" to "Classic" on our development machines.

Here is the blog post where I found this solution http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2014/04/httphandler-error-404-not-found.html