# Custom HttpHandler not working in IIS 7 but it is working in IIS 5

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working using custom IHttpHandler in my application. It is working fine in IIS 5. But now we are migrating to IIS 7 so we bought 2008 R2 server. Here it is not working. Kindly Help. you can reach me in maheswaran@lucidindia.com. Thanks in advance. 
This is my Custom Handler Code :

public class WebRequestHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
private void ProcessDataRequest(HttpContext context)
{
Controller controller = new Controller(); 
controller.ProcessDataRequest(context); 
}

## region IHttpHandler Members

public bool IsReusable 
{ 
get { return true; } 
} 

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
{ 
var segments = context.Request.Url.Segments; 
var request = segments[segments.Length - 1]; 

context.Response.Expires = -1; 

switch (request) 
{ 
case "data.lst": 
this.ProcessDataRequest(context); 
return; 
} 
}

## endregion

} 


And i am calling like this. 

this.client = new WebClient(); 
this.client.DownloadProgressChanged += this.OnProgressChanged; 
this.client.OpenReadCompleted += this.OnDataAvailable; 
this.client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("../data.lst?viewerID=viewer", UriKind.Relative), "GET"); 

But the ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) method is not called in IIS 7 after publishing. 

Kindly Reply to this post. Thanks in advance. 
This is my web.config content: configuration> 
appSettings>
add key="ChartHttpHandler" value="Storage=memory;Timeout=180;Url=~/temp/;"/> 
connectionStrings/> 
system.web> 
profile> 
properties> 
add name="searchSettings" defaultValue="" type="System.String"/> 
/properties> 
/profile> 
sessionState timeout="2"> 
/sessionState> 
compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> 
assemblies> 
add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/> 

authentication mode="Windows"/> 

httpHandlers> 
add verb="GET,POST" path="*.lst" type="App_Code.WebRequestHandler"/> 
/httpHandlers> 
pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/> 
system.webServer> 
validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> 
handlers> 
add name="WebRequests" verb="*" path="*.lst" modules="IsapiModule" 
scriptProcessor="%path%\aspnet_isapi.dll" ype="App_Code.WebRequestHandler"/> 
/handlers> 
/system.webServer> 
system.serviceModel> 
behaviors> 
serviceBehaviors> 
/serviceBehaviors> 
/behaviors> 
services> 
/services> 
/system.serviceModel> 
/configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Check out the related question [HttpHandler not working in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465859/httphandler-not-working-in-iis-7)

To resume, use the   `<system.webServer> <handlers>` instead...