# Registering HttpHandler for IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, webforms, ihttphandler

Very simple question, but nonetheless confusing. According to the Microsoft documentation, it is necessary to register a HttpHandler (used to serve images dynamically from DB) in the <handlers> section of the Web.Config file:

[How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This was also specified in a previous answer on this topic:

[HttpHandler not Working in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465859/httphandler-not-working-in-iis-7)

The confusion stems from the fact that I currently have it working in an ASP.NET Web Forms project without any entry in the config file. Can someone shed some light on this and if it may effect the performance of the handler for this particular task?

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't entirely clear in your question, but in the comments we have established that you are asking why a handler that's exposed via an ASP.NET .ashx file does not need to be mapped. The answer is simple: when ASP.NET is installed it adds a global handler to IIS7 for the *.ashx extension with the name SimplerHandlerFactory-Integrated and SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0. This handler simply acts like a wrapper and executes the underlying IHttpHandler implementation that is pointed to by the ASHX.

Comment: It's a 4.0 Integrated Mode app pool. No handlers or httpHandlers sections in my only config file. I do have httpRuntime and modules sections. Should I include these in the question?

Comment: No, I'm just not sure what you mean when you're talking about a handler then. Do you mean something like an ASHX???

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting to the database with a generic ASHX IHttpHandler.

Comment: Ah, then that's because the *.ashx extension is already mapped to the default ASP.NET SimpleHandlerFactory. I will update my answer.

Comment: Aha, thanks! MS documentation steps are kinda redundant then... :)