# could not create type XYZ.ashx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When I am trying to build my solution I am getting Could not create type Upload.ashx.I am pulling out my hair to solve this.Can anyone suggest me how to rectify this problem.And I don't know how to actually append the namespace to the class?

As I am having 
Here is my code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="vb" CodeBehind="Upload.ashx.vb" Class="Upload" %>
```

And this is my dir structure:

```
wwwroot/Test/Myproject
```

Comment: Please can you post the full error you are getting?

Comment: This is the one error I'm getting "could not create type Upload.ashx".And I think I should add the namespace to It can you help me out how to add a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a thing as an .ashx.vb file type.

Try changing your top line to:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Upload" %>
```

and then just put your code behind code in the .ashx file

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Upload" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Class Upload : Implements IHttpHandler

    'Code here....

End Class
```

Alternatively, have you tried building your code?

See this similar question for more help:

[Custom Http Handlers IIS7 and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272971/custom-http-handlers-iis7-and-asp-net)

Comment: I have an Upload.ashx and Upload.ashx.vb.Actually I am calling the codebehind from this so I have mentioned as Upload.ashx.vb

Comment: What happens if you change it so that the scripting is in the .ashx file like my example? Do you still get an error?

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few hours over this error "could not create type", and it may not help your exact problem

I had split my codebehind across many partial classes, all called "restserver" apart from one which was called "restServer" (note the capital S) it was that small difference that was causing the error, I changed them all to the same case and it worked perfectly.

VS isn't very helpful when working with ASHX files.

Comment: Actually I figured it just as the previous project was done with website and  I am working with webforms and that I realized after many suggestions and tricks and at last got working!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it is at the top of google at the moment, so for anyone looking: In a website project, the handler directive expects different parameters for websites and webapps. In this case (website) was looking for codeFile instead of (webapp) codeBehind:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="vb" CodeFile="Upload.ashx.vb" Class="Upload" %>
```

Comment: No, CodeFile isn't supported by the WebHandler directive.

Answer (score 0):

Add below tag

```
<%@ Assembly  Name="YourNameSpace.YourHandlerClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=90e3045b123af1c3" %>
```

above your WebHandler tag

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="vb" CodeBehind="Upload.ashx.vb" Class="Upload" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing a thread but I just had the same issue. The suggestion for Assembly Name by @sagar-s didn't work for me. So I tried this and I got a good build (not sure yet about actual functionality) :

```
<%@ Assembly Src="~/MyService.ashx.cs" %>
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyService.ashx.cs" Class="Namespace.MyService" %>
```

The Src and Name attributes are mutually exclusive. The CodeBehind attribute and Src attribute are redundant. I haven't tried to see if Src will be adequate if CodeBehind is removed. No time to experiment at almost 3am here - or to read docs which may clarify such things. HTH