# elfinder with MVC 3 and IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

Im trying to use elfinder in my MVC 3 application and using this .NET connector
: http://elfinderconnectornet.codeplex.com/ for elfinder. And this connector works with http handler configured in section  in WebConfig. For example:

for url like : 
192.168.0.17:9002/elfinder.connector?_=1347370006351&cmd=open&target=&init=true&tree=......

i have a handler in web config

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="elfinder.connector" type="ElFinder.Connector.Connector" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

and in  global.asax.cs `routes.IgnoreRoute("elfinder.connector");`to ignore this url in "Controller/Action" routing.

When im running this code  in VisualStudio localhost all works fine but on IIS 7 i have an 404 error.

May be IIS have custom config for httphandlers? some checkbox need to be checked :)
Any idea?

Comment: finded solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272971/custom-http-handlers-iis7-and-asp-net/1273021#1273021)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error because I didn't have read permissions on the directory. You must give, at least, read permission to see the folders and files.

Hope it helps. Regards.