# How would you add a httphandler for an ASPX url to Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, httphandler

Using Umbraco 4.11.1, I am trying to implement a custom httphandler and having no fun getting it to work.  I have perfectly functioning stand-alone web site on the same computer in which the handler works, but when I moved it to Umbraco, no dice.  Therefore I figure something in Umbraco is interfering with the httphandler.  The configuration looks like this:

Added to httpHandlers in the Umbraco web.config section:
    <add verb="*" path="ChartHost.aspx" validate="false" type="MyCompany.Web.ChartHost"/ >

Added to appSettings:
    <add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd,~/ChartHost.aspx" />

The result is the asp default 404 not found page (not the umbraco-generated version at least, so a little progress is made).  I think this is a little different because it's mapping an ASPX extension and I think Umbraco is trying to rewrite URLs with ASPX in them.  I also added some mappings for the ASHX extension that are working just fine - just not the ASPX mapping.  Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

I also asked this question two days ago on the umbraco forum (no answer yet) in case you come across it:  http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/8754-How-to-register-custom-HttpHandler

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HttpHandler not working in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465859/httphandler-not-working-in-iis-7):

> Registration of HttpHandlers is different for IIS7 than for previous
>   versions of IIS. Specifically, you register the handlers in the
>   web.config section named `<system.webServer><handlers>` not in
>   `<httpHandlers>`.
>
> See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272971/custom-http-handlers-iis7-and-asp-net/1273021#1273021) for an example.

Comment: Douglas, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using Windows 8 and tried the handlers section, but this made no difference.  Plus, I added other httphandlers for some ASHX files that work fine.  It's just this handler for the ASPX file that won't work.

Comment: Douglas, after I applied your solution and upgraded to Umbraco 6, it is working.  Thanks!